# SQL - Insert 1000 values fast

Tags: php, sql

I have a file with 1000 rows of codes (ex:9111111000085 9111111000023 etc).

What is the best way to insert all of this at once into the database without staying one day and writing the sql code?

[image]

Comment: what is your file ? Could you give us some lines ?

Comment: Use your databases function that loads data from a file.  That generally works pretty well.

Comment: Write a script to do it for you

Comment: Inserting 1000 codes is a 5-minute task (let's concede 30 minutes if you include paperwork). I honestly can't imagine a way to make it a 1-day work :-?

Comment: i edited the question and put a link to the file

Comment: I get MS Excel and text lists every day, where data needs to be adjusted and inserted into the database. So this sounds like a good exercice for you to learn how to do this very fast.

Comment: I am thiking to make a string with all the codes and explode them by break line and than do foreach and insert db.

Comment: Do you need to do it via PHP or directly in database? Which data base? Do you need as an script for those particular values or it need to be done more than one time with different files in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what data base are you using. You can search for "Bulk Insert" for your data base, it allows you to insert  complete file in one step.

If you need to create an instruction like this:

```
INSERT CodesTable VALUES
(91111),
(91112),
...
(91999)
```

You could open/copy&past the file in query editor. Make a search and replace, searching for new line character (enabling regular expression **'\n'** usually, verify your software version) and replace it for **'),('** without quotes, or supposing new line is '\n' you could replace with **'),\n('** without quotes.
Then add the first line **'Insert table values('** (without quotes).

Verify that last entry have a closing **')'** (without quotes).

Run the script or save it for later use.