# jQuery Countdown Timer for Games

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a solid countdown timer for a queeze game, that is not very easy to hack.

I tried to create my own timer, but I feel that is too fragile to hacking:

```
    var counter = 10;
    var timer = null;

function countdown(){
    if (counter == 10) {
        $(".time_box").html(counter);
    }
    if (counter <= 0) {
        stopInterval();
    }
    else {
        counter--;
        $(".time_box").html(counter);
    }
}
function reset() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    counter=0;
}
function startInterval() {
    $(".time_box").html(counter);
    timer= setInterval("countdown()", 1000);
}
function stopInterval() {
    clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Any ideas for security improvments?

Comment: Javascript is not the place for security.

Comment: Yes. Never pass a string into a `setInterval` or `setTimeout`: Do `setInterval(countdown, 1000);` instead. It's an XSS issue.

Comment: If you want security I recommend pinging back intervally via AJAX against a server-side deadline.

Comment: why did you ask the same question twice..? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253808/jquery-countdown-for-games#26253808 Are you having another one account for sock puppetting.?

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird It's possible to modify if its encrypted.. The user could just run `counter = -99999` in the console.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy , YES , both accounts were created 14 days ago You can check it out . :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy ,  This user is NOT ONLY SOCK PUPPET BUT Driving site to WRONG direction , Check his Question , Link in HIS Question redirects to PORN SITE . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038151/sql-insert-1000-values-fast
I already flagged this user and Question Hope you do the same to improve quality of website (And not degrade)

Comment: What is the concept behind ajax countdown, does it ping the server every 1 second?

Comment: @Speedwheel  , Stop posting PORN LINKS in your Question , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038151/sql-insert-1000-values-fast

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/yhoobhxth/ since when notepad is considered porn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is not really the place for security, but 1 recommendation I could give to reduce the risk of the user intervening is to encapsulate your code so that it cannot be modified outside of the object.

For example at the moment I could simply run the following in the browser console to gain myself extra time:

```
counter = -99999
```

However if you were to encapsulate your logic so that `counter` isn't exposed this wouldn't be possible.

```
var MyFunction = function(){

   var counter = 10;
   var timer = null;

   function countdown(){
       if (counter == 10) {
           $(".time_box").html(counter);
       }
       if (counter <= 0) {
           stopInterval();
       }
       else {
           counter--;
           $(".time_box").html(counter);
       }
    }
    function reset() {
       clearInterval(timer);
       counter=0;
    }
    function startInterval() {
       $(".time_box").html(counter);
       timer= setInterval(countdown, 1000);
    }
    function stopInterval() {
       clearInterval(timer);
    }

    return {
      startInterval: startInterval
    }

}();
```

Then call the following to start the count down:

```
MyFunction.startInterval();
```

Now a call to `counter` in the browser console wouldn't work, and neither would `MyFunction.counter`.

Comment: Do you know how can I retrive the counter value? So I know at what time the countdown stopped.